# What's so special about involute curves??

Tags: geometry, physics, plane-curves, curves

An involute curve (specifically, an involute of a circle) is very commonly used to define the shape of the teeth on a gear. Apparently this idea goes back to Euler.

Why is this? What special mathematical properties of an involute curve make it suitable for use in gears?

As far as I know, an involute is a curve formed by "unwinding string" from a circular hub. Is this imaginary piece of string somehow related to the functioning of the gear.

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute_gear) has a nice animation of involute gears, but it gives no insight into the mathematics (for me, anyway).

For easy reference, the involute of a circle of radius $a$ has parametric equations
\begin{align}
x(t) = &a(\cos t+t \sin t) \\
y(t) = &a(\sin t-t \cos t)
\end{align}
The equations give a spiral shape, but a gear tooth would use only a small portion of the spiral, with values of $t$ ranging from $0$ up to around $\pi/6$, maybe.

Comment: I assume you've seen [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rapidproto/mechanisms/chpt7.html)? "Although many tooth shapes are possible for which a mating tooth could be designed to satisfy the fundamental law, only two are in general use: the cycloidal and involute profiles. The involute has important advantages -- it is easy to manufacture and the center distance between a pair of involute gears can be varied without changing the velocity ratio."

Comment: @Rahul. Yes, I have seen it. Thanks. But I don't understand either point. I'd say involutes are difficult to manufacture, because CAD/CAM software doesn't handle them very well (only via laborious approximations). Straight lines or circles would obviously be easier. I didn't understand the second point, either. And these notes don't really say anything about the geometry of the involute. I suppose Euler explained everything, maybe.

Comment: Maybe of interest http://qtcgears.com/tools/catalogs/PDF_Q420/Tech.pdf, see section 2. Have fun!

Comment: See also these vídeos https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QM0juVXW54 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dh83mGUCiws